# How do I get a variable outside a try block

Tags: java

I have a function which will get the amount of currency a user has in a game, and return it as int tokens. I can't figure out how I should make it so it does this, as the variable isn't coming out of the try block.

```
    try {
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        result.next();
        int tokens = result.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int newToken = tokens + amnt;
```

Comment: It's not coming out because you don't necessarily run through your `try` block. If you declared `tokens` outside of try, then maybe it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply define tokens outside of the try block:

```
int tokens = 0;

try {
    result = statement.executeQuery();
    result.next();
    tokens = result.getInt(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int newToken = tokens + amnt;
```

Comment: And...you know...don't just ignore database errors. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Declare tokens outside of the try block but assign it inside the try block.  As this is a primitive, you don't need to instantiate the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `tokens` before the try block

```
  int tokens = 0;
  try {
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        result.next();
        tokens = result.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int newToken = tokens + amnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it outside the try-block and initialize it with some kind of default value.

Answer (score 0):

just declare the variable `token` outside `try`,write something like this

```
int tokens=0; //here 
try {
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        result.next();
         tokens = result.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int newToken = tokens + amnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you simply can't. Think of it as a local variable in a function. Can you use it in another one?

> how I should make it so it does this

You should declare it outside the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
int newToken = 0;
try {
    result = statement.executeQuery();
    result.next();
    newToken = result.getInt(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
newToken += amnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said, defining it outside of the try block will solve your issue. This is due to the variable scope being limited to within the try clause, or within the braces `{ }`

The same goes for variables defined inside **if-else clauses**, **functions** and **classes**.